# Error in Init statement, not sure of passing vector in viterbi

Tags: r

```
Error in E[, ] = emissionProbs[, ] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Calls: initHMM
```

This is the warning coming.

```
library(HMM)

transitions <- read.table("/home/subjects/comp90016/assignments/assignment3/transitions.txt")

emissions <- read.table("/home/subjects/comp90016/assignments/assignment3/emissions.txt")

hmm=initHMM(States=transitions[,1],Symbols=c("CP0","CP1","CP2","CP3","CP4"),transProbs=as.matrix(transitions),emissionProbs=as.matrix(emissions))


results<-viterbi(hmm,(my_vector[])[1]))
print (results)
```

There is vector called my_vector.
I am trying the following thing in Viterbi to derive a specific result but execution is getting halted due to the warning. Might be some other error while passing my_vector also.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
hmm=initHMM(States=transitions[,1],Symbols=c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20),transProbs=as.matrix(transitions),emissionProbs=as.matrix(emissions))
```

This was the error. Thanks